# Variable is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-graphview

I have check out answers like thees Variable is accessed within inner class. Needs to be declared final but it does not address what I am after.

I'm using GraphView to plot retrieved data from Google Firebase. The data is supposed to be a continuous line like this :

[image]

But when I run the program, it goes on like this instead :

[image]

Here's my lines of code :

```
public class RetrieveApp extends AppCompatActivity {

Integer hrValue;
ArrayList<Integer> array2; //array to contain hrValue
private ListView mListView;
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series ;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrieve_app);

    GraphView graph = (GraphView)findViewById(R.id.graph);
    series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();

    DatabaseReference userdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = auth.getCurrentUser();

    DatabaseReference ref = userdatabase.child(user.getUid());

    array2 = new ArrayList<>(); //array untuk hr



    //RETRIEVE DATA HR VALUE 
    ref.child("hrvalue").child("nilaihr").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            hrValue = dataSnapshot.child("tmpHR").getValue(Integer.class);
            showData(dataSnapshot);
            double y,x ;
            x = 0.0;
GraphView graph = (GraphView)findViewById(R.id.graph);
        series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
            for (int i=0; i<1000; i++){
                x = x+i;
                y = hrValue;
                series.appendData(new DataPoint(x, y), true, 1000);
            }
            graph.addSeries(series);
        }
```

Everytime I try to move these two lines to onCreate,

```
GraphView graph = (GraphView)findViewById(R.id.graph);
        series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
```

The `graph.addSeries(series)` line keeps on telling me :

> Variable 'graph' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be
>   declared final.

What should I do to address this problem? Any kind of help would be appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: You can keep the declaration statement in the global and initialization in the same position to fix this

Comment: I have defined GraphView graph; in public class, and  graph=(GraphView)findViewById(R.id.graph); to onCreate. But now i don't know where to put series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to do what the error message *implies* that you should do.  Declare `graph` as `final`.  Like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    final GraphView graph = (GraphView)findViewById(R.id.graph);

    ...

    ref.child("hrvalue").child("nilaihr").addChildEventListener(
        new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                ...

                graph.addSeries(series);
            }
        });
     ...
```

The rule (prior to Java 8) is that an inner class can only use a local variable that is declared in an enclosing scope (like `graph` is ...) if the variable is declared as `final`.

In Java 8, they relaxed this rule.  Now the variable only needs to be *effectively final* at the point at which it is captured.  (Your code would be valid if compiled with a Java 8 compatible compiler.)

Comment: (Potential down-voters please note.  I am fully aware of the duplicate link.)